# How to dynamically export inline javascript with assetic in twig templates?

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, inline, assetic

I am trying to clean up my html output in a Symfony2 Project. What really bothers me is that I dont really know how to export inline JS dynamically. For example: I need to initialise Jquery Datatables, but not on every page, most of the pages have their own specific inline js. Im searching for a way to just extend a twig block with my js snippets, that gets grouped together and loaded by assetic from an external (virtual) .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use template inheritance and have a parent javascript/jquery block.  Jquery is the same as javascript so you can include that in one block or have a seperate one.  If you are using a variable, then pass that variable to the base jquery section.  For your different pages, you need to extend the base twig file and either add to the javascript block by including the parent or overriding it entirely.

base twig file has basic html layout with js and css blocks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
            <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
        {% endblock %}
        {% block js %}
            <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
        {% endblock %}

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
        <div id="footer">
            {% block footer %}
                &copy; Copyright 2011 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is inherited by the child page

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block js%}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
        Welcome on my awesome homepage.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thats how i am currently using it :D My question is, i want one block (for example call it inlinejs) to hold all kind of snippets like `$('.ajaxsearch').click(function() {var input = $(this).parent().find('input') etc...` and then _somehow_ use assetic to load this block via `<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/snippets.js"></script>` rather than having it all in my source. I like clean output :)

Comment: I understand you want a clean output, but that approach may not work best. The single output would potentially change from page to page and would require it getting recompiled constantly. With different files, not all would be used on each page and the caching would work better. I think a better approach is to group your .js files into as few as possible, minimify them all, and allow a few files to be called on each page load. I think that will improve caching and still keep the number of files to a minimum, but more than one.